# Как выполнить метод спустя какое-то время в Spring MVC приложении?

Tags: java, spring, дата, время

Необходимо отправить оповещение пользователю спустя какое-то время(условно, через час). Как можно в `Spring` приложении сделать тайм-аут некий. Будет ли здесь уместен вариант со `Thread` от многопоточности или есть какие-то более современные и подходящие технологии для работы со временем в `Spring`?

Comment: `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool`, метод `schedule` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Spring Schedullers:**

В Spring есть интегрированные scheduller-ы. Они очень просты в использовании, настройке, а так же имеют большое количество документации. Их можно настроить как по cron, так и по фиксированным временным интервалам.

Из плюсов:

1. Одна строка кода - 1 задача(работа с аннотациями).
2. Достаточное количество документации
3. Быстрая интеграция и настройка

Из минусов:

1. При краше scheduller'а не всегда можно отловить ошибку
2. Сложен в отладке
3. Логирование нужно прикручивать самому через другие библиотеки

**Qaurtz Schedullers:**

Есть стороння библиотека, которая так же время от времени дорабатывается и поддерживается. Она не так понятна по документации, как Spring, но имеет встроенное логировании выполнения задач в базу данных.

Из плюсов:

1. Есть встроенное логирование в базу данных
2. Легок в отладке

Из минусов:

1. Очень много кода. Порой для одной задачи нужно создать около 2 классов.
2. Мало документации.
3. Долгая интеграция в Spring-проект. Сложная настройка.